# ECLIPSE ANDROID DEVICES DISAPPEAR

Tags: android

I have a problem with the Android emulator. After I run my application on a device it disappear from DDMS at some moment with no reason, even if it is still started. The only way to run again is to close the previous emulator and reopen it by running my application.

Do you have any solution for this strange error ? I must say that I can't deactivate my firewall if that is the problem. Also I tried to reset ADB but still doesn't work.

Comment: Is your application still in the foreground when this happens?

Comment: Do you mean your application vanishes or the emulator?

Comment: Have you restarted Eclipse only?

Comment: yes it is still in the foreground. The application still continues to work and the emulator is working but dont appear in Eclipse DDMS. If I restart eclipse, after a time, it happens again.

Answer (score 1):

**An answer for others that will come here looking for a solution.**

You just need to restart ADB (kill-server and then start-server).

More details on how to do so: http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/android-disappearing-emulator-restart-adb-server/